# Any difference in speed between checking a NSSet using objectsPassingTest: vs containsObject:

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, search, nsset

Is there a difference in speed between checking a NSSet if it contains a certain object using  [ containsObject:] vs using [ objectsPassingTest:block] with the stop variable set to YES so that it stops after first match?

Also, if the set contains objects of a custom class, my understanding is that the containsObject uses the isEqual: method to perform its check and hence this has to be overridden in the custom class.  Will this slow down the containsObject check as opposed to the case where the NSSset contains objects of Apple classes like NSString, NSNumber etc?

I plan to run some benchmarks when I get some time, but have an interview tomorrow and would like to have the answer handy for that one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question with a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should run the benchmarks you plan to, but you can guesstimate an answer.

An implementation of `containsObject:` might iterate calling `isEqual:` on each member; while an implementation of `objectsPassingTest:` might iterate, call the block on each member, and the block calls `isEqual:`...

I think you can guesstimate based on that. Have a good interview, though if the interviewer reads SO...

Answer (score 0):

Even I have problems with this kind of Qs on SO, I will (partially) answer to it. And I do not think that the interviewer will get the final result, but your thoughts on it.

Both do a check with `-isEqual:`. But `-containsObject:` can do it directly, while `-objectPassingTest:` has to call a block.This might not be expensive, but since the code to execute is not expensive, too, this might cause a performance impact.

Beside this `-containsObject:` can use hashing to find an object. `-objectPassingTest:` in `NSSet` cannot, since it has no idea of what the test is. The block cannot do this neither, because he gets the objects one by one.

However, if you have mutable objects in the set, what object of custom classes are typically, no hashing can be done, because it is impossible to implement useful hashing on mutable objects in a collection.

So my estimation: Having immutable objects with a properly implemented `-hash`, `-containsObject:` will beat `-objectPassingTest:` by far, otherwise not that much.

Comment: Wonderful answer (my thoughts too...) but, any real-world test results? and does a simple "NSString" match your bill of "properly implemented -hash" for that matter? I need VERY FAST matching, in (potentially) long lists of file-paths. I want to know if I need to write my own stuff here, or will simple NSSet do the work just fine.